# Symbol visibility using g++

Tags: linux, g++, visibility, symbols, hidden

I compiled a C++ library under Linux/Mac with its symbols hidden. I've used `__attribute__ ((visibility("hidden")))` for all my classes and compiled with options (`-c -O2 -fPIC -MMD -MP -MF`). Under Mac, using  [MacDependencies](http://code.google.com/p/macdependency/), the job is done just fine as I see only my exports (I actually saw the difference before and after).

However, I noticed that using `nm` I still see all the names of the symbols. This happens under both Mac and Linux.

Why is that? Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: On Linux are you using `nm -D` to show the dynamic symbol table?  The visibility only applies to the dynamic symbol table.

Comment: nm -D gives me indeed the correct "list", Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Public or hidden, symbols are still there. `nm` shows all symbols. The difference is that hidden symbols are not available to the dynamic linker, i.e. not exported and can not be interposed.

You might also like the following  `man gcc`:

```
   -fvisibility=default|internal|hidden|protected
       ...
       A good explanation of the benefits offered by ensuring ELF symbols
       have the correct visibility is given by "How To Write Shared
       Libraries" by Ulrich Drepper (which can be found at
       <http://people.redhat.com/~drepper/>)---however a superior solution
       made possible by this option to marking things hidden when the
       default is public is to make the default hidden and mark things
       public.  This is the norm with DLL's on Windows and with
       -fvisibility=hidden and "__attribute__ ((visibility("default")))"
       instead of "__declspec(dllexport)" you get almost identical
       semantics with identical syntax.  This is a great boon to those
       working with cross-platform projects.
```

Comment: Thank you Maxim, definitely got the difference now. A further question arises though: How can I see such symbols' table under Windows? Thanks again.

Comment: Probably `depends.exe` or `nm` from cygwin.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll give it a try tomorrow. Do you know of any way to actually remove those symbols from the output of nm?

Comment: makr4o already gave you the answer: `nm --dynamic` and `nm --extern-only` depending on what you want.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant to say is: is there any way to compile/link/strip/etc my shared library so that those names are not shown with a plain 'nm'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994741/symbol-visibility-using-g/4995608#4995608

Comment: `weak` symbols could be useful.

Answer (score 7):

You can [`strip`](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/strip1.html) your binary to remove any unneeded symbols.

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried to tick "Strip" from within Netbeans but it didn't do the trick. I tried now by hand with --strip-all and it looks like I got the result I was expecting. Thanks to all who partecipated!

Answer (score 3):

On OSX (not sure about others) I found the following.

As mentioned by Maxim, using `-fvisibility=hidden` or `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` still puts the symbol in the symbol table, it just gets marked as unexported. The easiest way to see this is with `nm`, e.g:

```
$ nm libfoo.dylib 
...
0000000000001fa0 t __Z10a_functionv
0000000000002140 T __Z17a_public_functionv
...
```

If the letter after the address is lowercase it means it isn't exported. Here `a_function()` is hidden, and `a_public_function` has default visibility.

To strip the non-exported symbols from the symbol table you can use `strip -x`, which according to the man page:

> -x    Remove all local symbols (saving only the global symbols).

```
$ strip -x libfoo.dylib
$ nm libfoo.dylib 
...
0000000000002140 T __Z17a_public_functionv
...
```

I believe (but am not 100% sure) that using `hidden` doesn't *just* amount to changing a flag, and 'unhiding' the symbols wouldn't be trivial.

Comment: The `strip -x` command is what I was looking for to remove the local symbols from the table completely, ie can't be seen using `nm`.