# How to make symbols available in .dynsym such that it can be called by a dynamically loaded .so

Tags: c, linux, qml

Getting unresolved symbol error when I am calling a native API from QML plugin. My investigation (readelf for the native elf) shows that the symbols which I am trying to access is not present in the `.dynsym`.

If I use `-rdynamic` option while compiling native elf, I am getting all the symbols added to `.dynsym`; but I don't want that.

If I use `-fpic` and `-shared` option, I can see some functions are getting to `.dynsym`, but I am not able to understand how the selection is made. 
I want to avoid using `dlopen()`.

Comment: Show the exact commands used in compiling the plugin. Read also [*How to Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf). Read about the `visibility` attribute (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4994741/841108) and [that](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility)...)

Comment: The compilation options are:  -fstack-protector -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wall -fno-builtin.  I tried with visibility as well, but it didn't help..

Comment: Use `-Wl,-dynamic-list,dynsym.syms` with file `dynsym.syms` containing `{ foo; bar; baz; }` (where `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` are the names of the symbols you want exported in the object.